# Adding left or right margin to background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am trying to give a background image a space from left or right.

[image: Image 1]

As you see in that picture the first sector is fine, the background image has space on the left and the content block is as I want.

The second sector should be the the opposite, content block right and the image on the left.

I solved this by:

```
background: url(/bilder/2.jpg);
background-position-x: 300px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

for the first block, but for the second block this CSS does not work

```
background: url(/bilder/2.jpg);
background-position-x: -300px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

Is there a possibility to give a background image a `margin-left` or `margin-right`?

Answer (score 1):

You can move background image. 
Example:

```
background-position: right 20px bottom: 10px;
```

Maybe you should show us your html code.

Answer (score 0):

`background-position-x` measures the distance from the left border, so you should use `background-position-x: 20px;` (approximately)  for the second image.

But I wouldn't use `background-size: cover` here (it really covers the whole element/div), and I am wondering if you really used this on the page whose image you posted?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your first ideas, I played arround a bit and think I solved one problem getting another one

[Demo Page here](http://www.vb.mtbr.it/111.html)

As you see, the pictures the layout is fine (on big screens) but now, how can I get a position to the pictures. In section 2 I can see the right part of the image and the biker is on the left part of the picture.